# How to create integers with increasing digits in it more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

The above code provides the list of integers whose digits are in ascending order. But with increasing numbers of digits, it becomes less efficient. Is there a way I any way I can make the code more efficient? Can we make it work for digits more than 30?

```
def gen_dig(digits):
    """Assumes digits is an integer;
    Returns a list containing integers with digits in ascending order"""
    lst=[]
    start=int('1'+'0'*digits)
    end=int('1'+'0'*(digits+1))
    for num in range(start,end):
        if str(num)==''.join(sorted(str(num))):
            lst.append(num)
    return lst
```

Comment: Could you add an example input and desired output?

Comment: You need to choose a better algorithm. This brute force method will be slow no matter how you speed up any piece of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I know it's inefficient. But I couldn't think of any other algorithm better than this.

Comment: Don't go through all numbers and check if they meet the requirement. Only generate numbers that meet the requirement in the first place.

Comment: Do you really want all those numbers? Or do you just want to know how many there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method with recursion:

```
str_numbers = '0123456789'

def generate(number):
    yield from helper(number + 1, 1)

def helper(num_pos, num_from):
    if num_pos == 1:
        yield from str_numbers[num_from:]
    else:
        for i in range(num_from, 10):
            for n in helper(num_pos-1, i):
                yield str(i) + n

for i, num in enumerate(generate(10)):
    print(i, num)
```

Prints:

```
0 11111111111
1 11111111112
2 11111111113
3 11111111114
4 11111111115
5 11111111116

...

75575 88888899999
75576 88888999999
75577 88889999999
75578 88899999999
75579 88999999999
75580 89999999999
75581 99999999999
```

---

Quick benchmark using `timeit`:

```
from timeit import timeit

t1 = timeit(lambda: gen_dig(6), number=1)
t2 = timeit(lambda: list(generate(6)), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine:

```
6.965828249998594
0.009299607001594268
```

Comment: IMHO, OP could have implemented that himself. But it's also good to know that you're providing free coding services.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I tried to make it more efficient, but for it takes ~19 seconds for `generate(20)`. For `30` I haven't tried it.

Comment: I'd write that first line as `str_numbers = '0123456789'`. Much simpler.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, The code works smoothly. Learnt something new  today. :)

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for comb in combinations_with_replacement("123456789", num_digits):
    print(''.join(comb))
```

Note that according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement),

> if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be
>   produced in sorted order

So the order of outputs is guaranteed.

Meanwhile, the equivalent implementation in the doc suggests that within each output combination tuple, the elements follow the same order as the input iterable. Hence, the order of digits in each output combination is also guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion for an algorithm:

- get the start number, e.g. 2004050
- starting from the beginning, set all digits which are less than the first digit to the value of the first digit, i.e. 2**22**4**2**5**2**
- repeat from the second digit (still 2224252), third digit (still 2224252), fourth digit (2224**4**5**4**) up to the last digit (222445**5**).

That way you get the next increasing number. Make it a method. You'll notice that you can even tweak this a bit.

After that, add 1 to the number and repeat the process on each one. You'll get 2224456, 2224457, 2224458, 2224459.

When reaching 2224460, it will be transformed into the next increasing number 222446**6**.

I'm not sure it'll work out for numbers in the 10^30 range, but it will at least skip 11% of the numbers right at the beginning (1000... to 1111...). This should happen again at 1200... to 1222... and so on, so it *might* be fast enough.